# Limits of rhomobile (or any framework) vs Android and iOs SDK

Tags: android, frameworks, rhomobile

Im an android and ios developer since 1 year and I am very tired to develop first for one device and after that to the other device, and I thought about the idea of use a framework. I talk with a friend about frameworks and he said me that he use Rothmobile. I developed some apps for android and ios, apps that have maps, manage of bluetooth, wifi etc. The functions that I implemented to control this features are diferents in each device. 
In this point here is my question. Can I really solve this problems with Rhomobile or others frameworks? For example the last month raises googlemaps api v2 for android and I developed my app with it, do the frameworks adapt really fast to the new versions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question you need to understand something about the infrastructure underneath. Also be aware that you can build with RhoMobile hybrid and native applications, for Android, Windows Mobile, Windows CE, Windows XP/7, iOS and BlackBerrys.

RhoMobile is getting much better in the recent last release 2.2.1.13. So you could give it a try with a simple app and check the performance by yourself.

This could be very interesting if your app is quite big, therefore you don't have to work double. In addition google API are supported, as far as I know the MAP API.[Check here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/faq#how-to-use-native-google-map-view-on-android)

For further questions you should ask them in the forum of [launchpad](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/rhomobile-suite/discussions)

[RhoMobile Documentation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/home)

[FAQ](http://docs.rhomobile.com/architecturefaq)

Comment: You can also add a native extension for anything that RhoMobile doesn't support.  But post a message to Launchpad if something is missing